# Speed up solr indexing

Tags: solr, indexing, dataimporthandler, dih

Solr indexing takes too long.
I am using mysql with more than 30 million records.
I am using two level sub queries.
Please suggest me best practices for indexing data, so that i can speed up the process.

Comment: can u plz, paste link related to this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [SolrPerformanceFactors](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors) with [Indexing_Performance](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrPerformanceFactors#Indexing_Performance) and [ImproveIndexingSpeed](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveIndexingSpeed)